# What is the relation between class "type" and specific types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

What is the relation between class `type` and specific types?

I thought that specific types were subclasses of `type`, but:

```
>>> type
<class 'type'>
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.issubclass(type, object)
True
>>> builtins.issubclass(int, type)
False
```

Thanks.

Comment: No, `type` is the **type** of a class.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) has some excellent answers on that topic.

Comment: Remember this mantra: *everything* in Python is an object. That means classes are just another object, that have their *own* class (a metaclass - a class of a class).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. What class is `type`   an object of?

Comment: @Tim you can always check programmatically: `type(type)` or `type.__class__`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that specific types were subclasses of type

They aren't. Every class is an *instance* of `type`; `type` acts as the class for classes. `isinstance(class, type)` returns `True` while `issubclass` correctly returns `False`.

A case where `issubclass` returns `True` is with custom meta-classes (class of classes) that actually inherit from `type`. For example, take `EnumMeta`:

```
>>> from enum import EnumMeta
>>> issubclass(EnumMeta, type)
```

This is `True` because `EnumMeta` has `type` as a base class (inherits from it):

```
>>> EnumMeta.__bases__
(type,)
```

if you looked its source up you'd see it's defined as `class EnumMeta(type): ...`.

---

`issubclass(type, object)` returns `True` for everything because every single thing in Python is an object (meaning everything inherits from `object`).

Comment: Thanks. What class is `type`  an object of?

Comment: @Tim `type` is an instance of itself :-) (see `isinstance(type, type)`). This does get confusing and explaining it isn't sufficient in a single comment; you can take a look at [this nice article](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html) that explains these relationships.